# Is it possible to extract the name of a nested arrays?

Tags: reactjs

So Im trying to edit a document in Firestore, and in this modal i want show the documents current info.
So I get this map of arrays from the document.

```
{ "electrolux": [ "model1", "model2" ], "bosch": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ] }
```

Im trying to pre-fill my dynamic input fields with this, but I can not for the life of me understand how I can extract the name of each array since they can be named anything.

so my question is, is there a way to map through the above map to generate the dynamic fields and get the name of the array in the first input and the contents of that same array in the second field?

This is the current code Im running

```
const [passarTill, setPassarTill] = useState([{ brand: "", models: [] }]);

// handle input change from Brand field
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const name = e.target.name.toLowerCase();
    const value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const list = [...passarTill];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setPassarTill(list);
};

// handle input change from Models
const handleArrayChange = (e, index) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase().split(",");
    const list = [...passarTill];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setPassarTill(list);
};

// handle click event of the Remove button
const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...passarTill];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setPassarTill(list);
};

// handle click event of the Add button
const handleAddClick = () => {
    setPassarTill([...passarTill, { brand: "", models: [] }]);
};
```

Here is the code that renders the dynamic inputs

```
{passarTill.map((x, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <div className="flex flex-wrap">
            <label className="w-4/12">
              <p className="w-4/12">Tillverkare</p>
              <input
                className="border w-11/12 p-1.5"
                name="brand"
                placeholder="T.ex. Electrolux"
                value={x.tillverkare}
                onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
              />
            </label>
            <label className="w-6/12">
              <p className="w-full">
                Modeller (separera endast med kommatecken ",")
              </p>
              <input
                className="border w-full p-1.5"
                name="models"
                value={x.modell}
                onChange={(e) => handleArrayChange(e, i)}
              />
            </label>
            <div className="flex flex-auto items-end justify-end">
              {passarTill.length !== 1 && (
                <button
                  className="text-xs w-18 p-2.5 bg-gray-300"
                  onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                >
                  Radera
                </button>
              )}
              {passarTill.length - 1 === i && (
                <button
                  className="text-xs w-18 py-2.5 px-2 ml-1 bg-gray-300"
                  onClick={handleAddClick}
                >
                  Lägg till
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access both the key and the value of each entry in the object, use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```
let appliances = { "electrolux": [ "model1", "model2" ], "bosch": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ] };

let outputArray = [];

Object.entries(appliances).forEach(([brandName, modelsArray]) => {
  
  console.log(brandName); //electrolux
  
  console.log(modelsArray); //["model1", "model2"]

  outputArray.push({
    brand: brandName,
    models: modelsArray
  });
}

console.log(outputArray); // [ {"brand": "electrolux", "model": [ "model1", "model2" ]}, { "brand": "bosch", "model": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ]} ]
```

**Explanation:**

With `Object.entries`, each entry is accessed as an array of `[key, value]`.

Iterate through the entries with `forEach`.

Using the `appliances` object, the value of `[brandName, modelsArray]` at each iteration will be:

- `["electrolux", ["model1", "model2"]]`
- `["bosch", ["model1", "model2", "model3", "model4"]]`

The format of your initial state (`[{ brand: "", models: [] }]`) is an array of objects.

At each iteration, push a `{ brand: brandName, models: modelsArray }` object into your output array.

Your final output array would then be in the following format:

```
[
 //first object
 {
  "brand": "electrolux",
  "model": [ "model1", "model2" ]
 },
 //second object
 {
  "brand": "bosch",
  "model": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ]
 }
]
```

To better understand an object literal and view it in a structured format, you could use a JSON formatter. It will also enable you to check the validity of your format.

Comment: Thank you, now im beginning to understand =) im still very new to this. Do you have any tip on how i would construct a new map with the structure of:
{ ["brand": "electrolux", "model": [ "model1", "model2" ]],[ "brand": "bosch", "model": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ] };

I think this is what I need to then set to the state so that it populates my fields.

So I basicly need to loop trough the map as you explained, and push that into a map so that I then can update the state, and only do that once when run

Comment: The format you provided in your comment is invalid. An object needs [properties](https://javascript.info/object) (key-value pairs). You could use a JSON formatter to check the validity of a format. Looking at the format of your initial state (`[{ brand: "", models: [] }]`), the format you would need is an array of objects. Your desired output format would then be `[ {"brand": "electrolux", "model": [ "model1", "model2" ]}, { "brand": "bosch", "model": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ]} ]`. The answer has been updated for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` helps in accessing dynamic names with json object. learn more about [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
let obj = { "electrolux": [ "model1", "model2" ], "bosch": [ "model1", "model2", "model3", "model4" ] };
  Object.keys(obj).map(name=>{
    console.log(name); //prints - electrolux, bosch
    console.log(obj[name]) //if you need values
  })
```

Comment: Thanks man, that got me one step closer :D 
I think my next step is to recreate the array the fields create so i can update the state, so it pushes the state to the fields as they are connected. Im really new to this to trying to wrap my head around how all this works :PP